# Javascript function to slow down scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have javascript function that **moves an img to the right on scroll down** and is working just fine on desktops. 
It "fakes" `position: fixed` and this is messing it up on mobile phones.

Because on mobile phones scroll occurs way faster than on desktops, my `fake position:fixed` divs aren't `fixed` anymore, they go up and come back.

http://jsfiddle.net/denea/3gn6abq8/50/embedded/result/
On desktop works fine, but if you access it from a phone it's not.

I tried deboucing it with (negative values didn't work either):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var dontHandle = false;
    $('#home').on('scroll', function() {
        if (dontHandle) return; // Debounce this function.
        dontHandle = true;
  var dist = $(this).scrollTop();

  $("#header").css("top", dist);
  $('#cars').css('left', dist * 2);

   window.setTimeout(function() {
            dontHandle = false;
        }, 1); // Debounce!--let this handler run once every 1 milliseconds.

});
});
```

But no success.

I thought if there is a way to slow down the scrolling proccess on phones it would solve the issues. Still any other ideas would be great.

Comment: why don't you just use position:fixed;? Or just wrap it in a div, and give it the elements you want fixed position absolute;

Comment: @JacobGray if I use position:fixed, when I hover the button or car image, scrolling doesn't occur.

Comment: You could set them `pointer-events:none;`

Comment: @JacobGray I tried this, the problem is that I need the button to be clickable and with `pointer-events: none;` it's not clickable anymore.

Comment: https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll

Comment: @Thomas I'm not excluding my hands aren't growing from the right place, but even the demo provided doesn't work ( I mean there's nothing different from a document that doesn't have all that javascript code in it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `nicescroll`, as **Thomas** suggested.

If anyone ever needs it, here you get the slower scrolling: http://jsfiddle.net/denea/JPA4R/149/